# Wann kann man Einwortsätze schriftlich verwenden?

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation, interrogative

Wann ist es erlaubt, Sätze mit nur einem Wort zu verwenden? (In schriftlicher Form)

Ich meine keine Ausrufe (z.B. “Verschwinde!“) oder Begrüßungen, z.B. “Hallo“.,“Servus“ etc.

Paar Beispiele:

> Computer. Wir alle kennen sie, ...
>
> Ernsthaft? Du fährst ohne mich weg?
>
> Gemein. Wie kann er das nur tun?

Comment: Das ist nur eine Stilfrage.

Comment: Für gültige Sätze gibt es viele verschiedene Definitionen. Manche davon verlangen, das mindestens ein finites Verb enthalten ist. Danach wären manche deiner Beispiele keine Sätze. Was du dagegen als "Ausruf" bezeichnest, z.B. "Geh!" ist ein einfacher Imperativ und wäre nach einer solchen Definition ein Satz. Wegen dieser Menge an Definitionen glaube ich nicht, dass deine Frage eindeutig zu beantworten ist, ausser, nach der generellen Regel: "erlaubt ist, was funktioniert" (also transportiert, was man ausdrücken will).

Comment: Im ersten Beispiel klingt der Teil nach Computer eher wie ein Einschub. In diesem Fall ist ein Komma zu verwenden, z. B.: _Computer, wir alle kennen sie, sind aus unserem Alltag nicht mehr wegzudenken._

Comment: Erlaubt ist, was gefällt.

Comment: @clemens, in den anderen Fällen ist die Gelegenheit für ein Komma auch günstig.

Comment: @userunknown: Ja, stimmt auch wieder.

Answer (score 4):

Zunächst mal hat Janka mit seinem Kommentar recht:

> Das ist nur eine Stilfrage.

Daraus folgt, dass alle Antworten auf deine Frage keine sachlichen Antworten, sondern Meinungen des jeweiligen Antwortenden darstellen werden.

In nicht-sachlichen Texten (z.B. Erzählungen) ist es dem Autor überlassen, was er macht.

Je sachlicher und formeller ein Text jedoch ist (z.B. ein Schreiben an eine Behörde, geschäftlicher Brief- oder E-Mail-Verkehr), desto eher halte **ich persönlich** einen Satz, der keinen gültigen Satz im grammatikalischen Sinne darstellt, für unangebracht.

Und bei den drei Sätzen aus deinen Beispielen fehlt das Verb.

Allerdings kann ich mir auch in solchen Texten einen solchen Satz vorstellen, wenn dieser eine Konkretisierung des vorherigen Satzes darstellt.

Beispiel:

> Wir haben uns stets an die Streupflicht bei Glatteis gehalten. **Auch sonntags.**

Comment: *Auch sonntags* ist kein Satz. Nicht alles, was gross anfängt und einen Punkt hinten hat, ist ein Satz.

Comment: @tofro Der Fragesteller hat solche Konstrukte bereits in der Überschrift als "Satz" bezeichnet; ich selbst habe diese Bezeichnung lediglich übernommen. Außerdem schreibe ich in meiner Antwort doch ganz deutlich, dass es sich um "*keinen gültigen Satz im grammatikalischen Sinne*" handelt.

Comment: @tofro doch es ist ein Satz ob dus glaubst oder nicht

Comment: Das ist genau die Art von Diskussion, die diese Frage nicht beantwortbar macht und die ich in meinem ersten Kommentar angesprochen habe. Solange nicht definiert ist, was ein Satz ist, oder die Diskutanten sich darüber nicht einig sind, kann man schwerlich darüber diskutieren. Und das ist es nicht: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_(Grammatik)

Comment: Aus deinem zweiten Satz ergibt sich, dass du eine off-topic-Frage beantwortest.

Comment: @tofro Ob die Frage eine reine "Meinungsfrage" (und somit off-topic) ist, weiß ich nicht: Es geht im Endeffekt in dieser Frage um "guten Stil" - also um die Frage, ob etwas "guter Stil" ist oder nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Einwortsätze gibt es eigentlich nur in der gesprochenen Sprache. Ich schriftlicher Prosa kommen sie eigentlich nicht vor. Die einzige Ausnahme ist die wörtliche Wiedergabe gesprochener Sprache.

Allerdings kann man auch in Erzählungen oder Beschreibungen sowohl unvollständige Sätze als auch Einwortsätze einfügen. Manchmal. Nicht immer. Es kommt darauf an, für welchen Zweck der Text bestimmt ist, und ist letztendlich eine rein stilistische Frage bzw. eine Frage der persönlichen Note des Autors.